# RSpec tests pass individually but fail as suite because of ARGV

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have three RSpec2 test files, each of which passes individually. But running the suite with `rspec spec` (or `jruby -S rspec spec`) fails.

The problem: `ARGV` is being set to `["spec"]` and running my program with a `spec` argument changes its behavior. I try to handle this in my tests with:

```
before(:each) do
  ARGV.clear  # also tried: ARGV.delete_if { |val| true }
end
```

but the `puts ARGV` statement in my code indicates `ARGV` is still being set to `["spec"]`.

I've also created a `spec/spec_helper.rb` file with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    ARGV.clear
  end
end
```

with the same result. When I run tests individually, ARGV is empty. But when I run `rspec spec`, `ARGV` is `["spec"]`.

Possibly relevant background: I'm running under rbenv.

Comment: After putting `ARGV.clear` directly inside my code, the test suite runs properly.

And putting `ARGV.clear` inside RSpec works when I run a single test file.

Why won't RSpec clear ARGV when run as a test suite?!?!

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your code such that ARGV isn't mentioned in the methods you're testing.

For example, if you need to test that you can parse "play_jukebox", then do

```
def test_play_jukebox
  parse_options(["play_jukebox"])
end
```

and in your bin file, have

```
if $0 == __FILE__
  parse_options(ARGV)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my code needs to handle ARGV because passing command line params is part of the API. So I need to test it with various ARGVs, including an empty ARGV, right? The problem is that ARGV.clear works when I run individual test files but doesn't work when I run the test suite.

Comment: Why can't you just pass an array to your API?

Comment: I may be missing your point, and I may have confused you with my use of "API." I'll be more specific: "play_jukebox," "play_jukebox ~/Music/JAZZ/Art_Tatum," and "play_jukebox at" are all valid command line invocations of my program (the first plays a default directory tree and the latter two play the Art Tatum directory tree). Testing that first call requires ARGV to be empty, doesn't it?

Comment: Great! Thanks, Andrew. I'll be off the grid a few days but will try this in a few days and let you know how it worked out (unless Irene gets me! Let's hope this thing swings out to sea).