# RSpec fails suite, passes tests individually

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have two tests in my `spec` folder and they are both green when I run them individually:

```
rspec spec\temp_stab_target_spec.rb   
32 examples, 0 failures

rspec spec\mock_spec.rb
10 examples, 0 failures
```

but when I run all of them:

```
rspec spec
42 examples, 32 failures
```

Everything for `spec\mock_spec.rb` is passing and everything for `spec\temp_stab_target_spec.rb` is not

I did some research and found that I'm having the same issue as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156261/rspec-tests-pass-individually-but-fail-as-suite-because-of-argv).  When I check `ARGV`, it contains `spec`.  I tried using `before(:each) { ARGV.clear }` just as he did, but to no avail.

Also, when I check `ARGV` just running `rspec spec\temp_stab_target_spec.rb`, it's empty.

Can someone explain what's going on or help me fix it? I'm going to be expanding the suite and I would like to be able to run all the tests at once as opposed to individually.

In case it's pertinent, I'm running `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i386-mingw32]` and `rspec 2.12.2`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a minimal example (for example a single spec in each file that still reproduces the behaviour) and post that?

Comment: Small hint: Giving some Rspec examples will increase your chances on the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

don't use references to ARGV in your tests!

feed stuff like that into the code that you are testing. use constructors, factory methods or whatever helps to decuple the code from parts that are hard to test.